# AWS EKS Ingress Timeout On Any Non-Root Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-alb, amazon-eks

We have configured an Ingress resource on our EKS cluster with rewrites from `/.*` on the load balancer to the matching URI upstream. If we visit `staging.my-domain.com/`, we see a successful health-check response as expected. However, any other url, e.g. `/api/`, results in a timeout from the load balancer. Below is the configuration. (SSL is disabled for now while we get it figured out). Any help would be appreciated!

```yaml
# Ingress Controller: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/installation/
# YAML: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/alb-ingress.md
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: staging.my-domain.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: nlx-api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: our-api
            port:
              number: 80
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: our-api
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: our-api
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the configuration that ended up working:

```yaml
# Ingress Controller: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/deploy/installation/
# YAML: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/alb-ingress.md
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: example.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1 # this is where the problem was
  name: nlx-api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / # this was correct
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nlx-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your [Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) Target is wrong. Look at this general example from [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by  `(.*)`  will be assigned to the placeholder  `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in the  `rewrite-target`  annotation.
> For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following rewrites:
>
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new`  rewrites to  `rewrite.bar.com/new`

In your situation, if you try to access `staging.my-domain.com/`, you are rewrited to the same address. Everything is fine. But you can rewrite only this address. You should change your manifest like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: staging.my-domain.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  name: nlx-api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: staging.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: our-api
            port:
              number: 80
```

In this situation any characters captured by `(.*)` will be assigned to the placeholder `$1`(this is first capture group), which is then used as a parameter in the `rewrite-target` annotation.

Comment: Hm, I have actually used this configuration as part of the troubleshooting before and just tried it again. It says: `Failed build model due to ingress: our-namespace/our-api: prefix path shouldn't contain wildcards: /(.*)`

Comment: Try to add annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"`. You can read more [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#regular-expression-support). You can also see a description of [this bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41881). It looks like it still hasn't been fixed.